# Android onAppLeave/onAppReturn events

Tags: android

I am trying to implement `onAppLeave`/`onAppReturn` events in Android >= 4.0. These should be fired when the user leaves the app (goes to another app, presses home, etc) and returns to the app (i.e. the app is brought to the foreground where previously it was not). Currently, I am tracking lifecycle calls from all the activities in my app, determining when to fire the events based on the order of lifecycle calls. After testing on several devices, it seems that lifecycle events between activities in the same app occur in this order:

```
Time   Activity A    Activity B
----   ----------    ----------
 |     onPause
 |                   onStart
 |                   onResume
 v     onStop
```

Assuming this is correct,

- the `onAppLeave` event can be fired when `onStop` from one activity in the app isn't preceded by `onResume` from another activity in the app.
- the `onAppReturn` event can be fired when `onStart` in one activity in the app isn't preceded by `onPause` from another activity in the app.

Is this logic correct? Are there any situations where these assumptions are invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic, according to [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#CoordinatingActivities), is correct.
Other situations could arise when a user clicks on an email, phone, map, etc., link and starts another activity like phone dialer, gmail composer or maps.  A user would probably consider these activities the parts of the app, but this logic for firing onAppLeave event would not.